# Pygame Pong paddles not showing up

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a Ping Pong game in Pygame. Having some trouble getting the paddles to display on screen within a class. I have a feeling either my constructor init method is incorrect (although not throwing up any errors) or the display colour is overwriting the paddles.

Here's my code.

Program.py

```
import sys
import pygame

from settings import Settings
from paddles import Paddles
import game_functions as gf


def run_game():
    # Initialise pygame, settings and screen object.
    pygame.init()

    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width,ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Ping Pong')


    # Start the main loop for the game.
    while True:
        gf.check_events()
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings,screen)

    #Make paddles
    paddles = Paddles(screen)


run_game()
```

paddles.py

```
import pygame
import sys

class Paddles():

    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.paddle_l = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), [15, 250, 10, 100])
        self.paddle_r = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), [780, 250, 10, 100])

    def paddles(self):
        pass
```

settings.py

```
class Settings():
    """A class to store all settings for Ping Pong"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialise the game's settings."""
        # Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 800
        self.screen_height = 600
        self.bg_colour = (0,0,0)
```

game_functions.py

```
import sys
import pygame

def check_events():
    """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

def update_screen(ai_settings, screen):
    """Update images on the screen and flip to the new screen."""
    # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_colour)


    pygame.display.flip()
```

Like I said I'm not getting any errors, the game window just opens to a black background. The code worked when I put it inside a normal function but not a class.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the paddles to display?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're setting `paddles` outside of the "main loop?"

Moving `paddles` into your `update_screen` method gets them showing, at the very least.  However, this is newing up a new Paddles object each time `update_screen` is called.

```
def update_screen(ai_settings, screen):
    """Update images on the screen and flip to the new screen."""
    # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_colour)
    paddles = Paddles(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: that worked, thank you! I'm following the structure of the Alien Invasion project in Python Crash Course. I assumed it would work for my code as well. Btw, in order to get the paddles to move do i put the code inside paddles module?